# What is the difference between the Intel Core i7-4770 and i7-4790?

Tags: intel-core-i7

I would like to to know if there exists any vital differences between Intel's Core i7-4770 and Core i7-4790 apart from the clock speed.

Also, why are there so many processors coming out so quickly ?

Comment: The Haswell Refresh was planned when the original Haswell products were released.  As for the reason Intel had planned to release them earlier farther apart from the first Broadwell well products but that didn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this page (HTH): http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/443/Intel_Core_i7_i7-4770_vs_Intel_Core_i7_i7-4790.html

```
Pros and Cons summary
Core i7-4770                  Core i7-4790
********************************************
General recommendations:
None                          Clocked higher    

Drawbacks:
Runs at lower frequency       None
```

Comment: Many of the Haswell motherboards only need a UEFI(bios) update to be applied PRIOR to the install of the haswell refresh processor. So chances are good that many of the newer boards people bought can still be used with this new 4790.

Comment: It means there is no difference. Actually I have 4770 and purchased last month so get to know that latest is out so get confused that why they lauch so quickly for processor range.

Comment: The 4770 can actually be overclocked to nearly the same performance as an overclocked 4790.